# PHP Date: Every monday next 3 weeks (Google Calendar remake)

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I'm making a CRM-system, and I now need to offer people to make recurring events. For that they will have to fill out if it's daily, weekly, monthly or yearly, and everything like when you do it in Google Calendar.

But how will I get the dates in an array for "monday next 3 weeks" for example?

Answer (score 0):

```
$int_count = 3; // How many to repeat
$date = new \DateTime('next monday');
$result = array($date->format('Y-m-d'));
for ($i=1; $i<$int_count; $i++) { 
    $result[] = $date->modify('+1 week')->format('Y-m-d'); 
}

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-01-26
    [1] => 2015-02-02
    [2] => 2015-02-09
)
```

Comment: you're mixing new technologies (`DateTime` class) with old technologies (not using `DatePeriod` iterator). See my answer, it's cleaner

Comment: Says the guy who's first answer (since deleted) was to use strtotime... You can certainly use an iterator for this, but both answers are functionally identical and I'd say this one is much clearer for a novice to understand, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `DateTime` and `DatePeriod` classes. It's the most correct way to deal with dates now. It deals with timezones and DST shifts automatically. It's just the way you must do it.

```
$daterange = new DatePeriod(new DateTime('next monday'), new DateInterval('P1W'), 2);

$dates = [];
foreach($daterange as $date) $dates []= $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

print_r($dates);
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-01-26 00:00:00
    [1] => 2015-02-02 00:00:00
    [2] => 2015-02-09 00:00:00
)
```